# This calculator keeps performing addition

Tags: java, calculator

```
public class Calculator {

public static void main(String[] args){
    int answer;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input;
    System.out.println("Enter your operation please");
    input = scan.next();
    if(input.charAt(findsign(input))=='+'){
        answer = firstnumber(input)+secondnumber(input);
        System.out.println("Operation is addition");
        System.out.println("The answer is " + answer);
    }
    else if(input.charAt(findsign(input))=='-'){
        answer = firstnumber(input)-secondnumber(input);
        System.out.println("Operation is subtraction");
        System.out.println("The answer is " + answer);
    }
    else if(input.charAt(findsign(input))=='*'){
        answer = firstnumber(input)*secondnumber(input);
        System.out.println("Operation is multiplication");
        System.out.println("The answer is " + answer);
    }
    else if(input.charAt(findsign(input))=='/'){
        answer = firstnumber(input)/secondnumber(input);
        System.out.println("Operation is division");
        System.out.println("The answer is " + answer);
    }

}

public static int findsign(String input){
    int n=0;
    for (n=0;n<input.length();n++){
        if(input.charAt(n)=='+' || input.charAt(n)=='-' || input.charAt(n)=='*' || input.charAt(n)=='/'){
            break;
        }
    }
    return n;
}
public static int firstnumber(String input){

        String number1 = input.substring(0,findsign(input));
        int number = Integer.parseInt(number1);
        return number;
    }
public static int secondnumber(String input){
    String number2 = input.substring(findsign(input),input.length());
    int number = Integer.parseInt(number2);
    return number;
}


}
```

I do not see what is so difficult about this, but apparently the calculator keeps performing addition, and not their specified operations. I made them print the operation entered in order to see if the "if" statements work, and they do. However, they still keep performing addition. I'm not sure if it's just too simple I'm getting confused or what at this point...so if you can help that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You are off by one when parsing the second number:

```
String number2 = input.substring(findsign(input)+1,input.length());
//                                              ^^
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/JRal45)

Addition works because when you parse `2+3` and pass `"+3"` to parse an `int`, the operation is successful because `+` is a valid numeric prefix. If you try `2*3`, however, you would try parsing `"*3"` for an `int`, which is no longer valid.

Comment: I can't believed I missed that, but thank you so much. I feel ridiculously silly now ahahaha

Comment: @user3817390 You don't need to feel silly, because off-by-one errors are notoriously simple to make, yet they rank rather high on the list of hard-to-find bugs.

Comment: Absolutely. Seen a lot of that.

Answer (score 0):

secondnumber() should have "...substring(findsign(input)+1", in fact, for 3-2 it will return 3 and -2, and you will compute "3 - -2", which is 5 again, like "3+2".

A debugger or a little bit of System.out.println would have helped, as would have trying "3*2":

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "*2"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at Calculator.secondnumber(Calculator.java:51)
    at Calculator.main(Calculator.java:22)
```